# Mockito Verification of send mail method in another static class

Tags: java, mockito

```
public class SomeclassTobeTested {

    public int doSomethingAndSendMail(){
        //... doing something
        SomeStaticClass.sendEmail(args);
    }
}

Public static SomeStaticClass implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        sendMail();
    }

    public static void senMail(args){

     //starts the thread

    }
}

public class TestSomeClassToBeTested{

}
```

So now I have to verify whether `sendEmail` was called from `doSomethingAndSendMail()`? Which class should I mock? And not actually send the email.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot verify `static` methods with Mockito . You have to use Powermockito to do that.

However, I suggest you refactor your code so the `sendEmail` method is a member of an object, perhaps of a dependency. This dependency can then be mocked and the `sendEmail` method can be stubbed and verified with Mockito. Having to use Powermockito usually means bad practice.

More information can be found in these answers: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockit) and  [Why is using static helper methods in Java bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387385/java-why-is-using-static-helper-methods-bad)

Comment: How would you test it if the class under test used an email sending API such as Apache Commons EMail? Such APIs are object-oriented (no statics, with true objects), therefore not usually regarded as "bad practice"; yet, they can't be mocked with plain Mockito.