# Using Static methods in the helper class vs non-static

Tags: c#, oop, static-methods

I have a helper class that takes some object, processes it and returns back some instance of the other class or even the List of the objects.
What would be the best way: to make this helper method static or non-static?
The thing is that my app can create lots of the Car objects and I was thinking whether it could have a negative effect when each of them use the static helper?

Comment: Do you have some example code as will help to give the most appropriate answer to your question

Comment: @J.Doe Yup. Your car could have a flat tire. Jokes apart, can you show us some code please.

Comment: Do you need to mock some functionalities when testing your class (the original, not the helper class)? If so,  you shouldn't use static methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java why is using static helper methods bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387385/java-why-is-using-static-helper-methods-bad)

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is something that can be solved without deciding the helper object's life-cycle where you require it.

You should try to leverage dependency injection approach:

```
public class X
{
   public X(IHelper helper)
   {
        Helper = helper;
   }

   private IHelper Helper { get; }

   public void DoStuff() 
   {
        var result = Helper.DoOtherStuff(input);
   }
}
```

That is, `X` don't know whether Helper is always the same instance or if it's a transient object. This makes the code cleaner and more test-friendly, because you can mock the helper with a fake `IHelper` implementation to be sure that you're just testing `X`.

Comment: I'd change the type to `IHelper` in your example to emphasize there's no coupling between `X` and it's helper

Comment: I'd agree to this answer. Also, looks like Java community has same discussion over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387385/why-is-using-static-helper-methods-in-java-bad) and they've come to the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

Most helper or utility classes use static methods. You should only use non-static methods if you want to create multiple instances of your helper class, but since you just need a simple input -> function -> output, I would make the methods static.

Comment: This is wrong. You should use static classes / methods only if there is a good reason for them to be static, not the other way around.

Comment: @shay__ like it being a helper method that doesn't relate to any state or need to be overridden?

Comment: @shay__ Utility classes are usually static. instantiating an object for a single unrelated method is redundant. his suggestion is not wrong, you misinterpreted it.

Comment: @Stavm the fact that people "usually" do it does not mean it's the right thing to do. `HelperClass.GetRuntimeConfigurations()` does not relate to the object's state yet it is wrong to be static, you can't (easily) mock it for tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use static class with static methods, No instance, no derivation and only static methods in the class.

```
public static class HelperClass
{
   public static void HelperMethod()
   {
       // do something
   } 
}
```

Comment: Not very useful if needed in several places, since static can only be used in inner classes.